# How can I remap my camera button to switch back and forth between two apps?

Tags: applications, buttons

For my work as a bicycle delivery man, I use the phone for navigation and thus often need to switch between the delivery app and Google Maps. I'd like to configure the camera key of my Cubot Quest Lite to do exactly that.

The functionality I want is exactly the one that happens by default when double-tapping the Overview button. Double-tapping is just annoying and hard to get right every time, so I'd like to switch this task to the mechanical camera button, since I don't use the camera anyway. I tried several remapping apps so far, including Button Mapper and Button Remapper, but none of them could override the camera function of the button.

From what I've read, rooting the phone should make literally everything possible, however I'd prefer to not mess around with this stuff as I don't feel confident. Is there anything else I could try?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know how to make this work, but I ended up using the app [Full Screen Gestures](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agooday.fullscreengestures&hl=en) instead. It lets you configure actions for when you swipe inwards from the screen edges, and I simply configured it to start my desired apps on swipe, allowing me to effortlessly switch between them.